# Server losing UUID of banned players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When we banned players the vanilla way using:

```
/ban <player> [reason]
```

It worked, but pardoning players using

```
/pardon <player>
```

threw up an error telling us the player could not be banned. We installed a plugin to handle bans but banned players have been seen rejoining a couple of days later. It seems the issue is that once a player is banned, the server loses their UUID, meaning they become unbanned.

I can't find anything about this issue online, which makes me think it's unique to our server, but does anyone have an idea of how to confirm this is the case, and fix the issue?

Comment: It may have to do with your plugin.  Since it's a mod, I'm not sure we'd be able to help, but either way, we'd need to know which mod it is.

Comment: the issue seemed to be present before the plugin was installed, the plugin being installed just made it obvious that it was happening.

Comment: Retry on a server that was never modded. And what happens if you execute `/banlist`?

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to just keep the player names down on a notepad and ban them every time you run your server.